# PHP filter sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, unique-key

Have the following xml file with gallery in it

http://pastebin.com/GFykW0tc

I need to display tags (hidden in field-2)

So I created the following php code

```
<?php $galleries = eg_return_gallery();
    foreach ($galleries['projects']['items'] as $image)
 { 
  echo $image['field-2']
  } 
    ?>
```

How I could filter duplicate tags, so only unique tags are displayed?

eg_return_gallery - as it name implies return php array (see example below)

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "galeria"
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  ["items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(10) {
      ["filename"]=>
      string(27) "uploads/galeria-foty/01.jpg"
      ["width"]=>
      int(1050)
      ["height"]=>
      int(740)
      ["thumb-0"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["filename"]=>
        string(52) "ExtraGallery/thumbs/galeria-foty/01-fill-200-300.jpg"
        ["width"]=>
        int(200)
        ["height"]=>
        int(300)
      }
      ["thumb-1"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["filename"]=>
        string(0) "ExtraGallery/thumbs/galeria-foty/01-10-0-200-300-200-300.jpg"
        ["width"]=>
        int(100)
        ["height"]=>
        int(150)
      }
      ["field-0"]=>
      string(10) "Test text"
      ["field-1"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["field-2"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["field-3"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["field-4"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you trie to do anything already?

Comment: Tried using $filter = array_unique($galleries);
But it filters only top level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store each tag in a new array an then remove duplicates from that array:

```
<?php 
    $galleries = eg_return_gallery();
    $tags = array();

    foreach ($galleries['projects']['items'] as $image) { 
      $tags[] = $image['field-2'];
    } 

    $tags = array_unique($tags);   

    print_r($tags); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look the source of eg_return_gallery and how it works, but I recomend you to use one of those libraries http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php, specially SimpleXML.

But I think that you're having a problem with the structure of your XML - so I suggest you to read the XML specs http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006.